# Spring data JPA Spel - @Query Issue

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

I am having trouble getting SPEL and Spring data jpa to work

**Following is My Repository**

```
package eg.repository;
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>,JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyEntity> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM eg.domain.MyEntity e " +
            "WHERE e.title = :#{#filter.title}"
    )
    Page<MyEntity> list1(@Param("filter") MyFilter filter,Pageable pageable);
}
```

**Filter Component**

```
package eg.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("filter")
public class MyFilter {

    public String titleFilter() {
        return "%title%";
    }
    private String title = "title title1";
    public Long[] idFilter() {
        return new Long[] {
                1L, 2L
        };
    }
}
```

**Following is MyEntity**

```
package eg.domain;
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    ......
}
```

**Main Class**

```
LOG.info("Application initialized " + annotationConfigApplicationContext);
        MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository =
                    (MyEntityRepository) annotationConfigApplicationContext.getBean(MyEntityRepository.class);
        MyFilter filter = annotationConfigApplicationContext.getBean(MyFilter.class);
        PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0, 5);
        Page<MyEntity> page = myEntityRepository.list1(filter,pageRequest);
        List<MyEntity> entities= page.getContent();
        for(MyEntity entity: entities){
            System.out.println(entity.getId() + " TITLE " +  entity.getTitle());
        }
```

Following is the error that I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myEntityRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page eg.repository.MyEntityRepository.list1(eg.service.MyFilter,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable) but parameter 'filter' not found in annotated query 'SELECT e FROM eg.domain.MyEntity e WHERE e.title = :#{#filter.title}'!
```

Comment: Why do you not just give the title as parameter and not it like `@Query("SELECT e FROM eg.domain.MyEntity e WHERE e.title = :filter")`?

Comment: I am just trying to get Spel to work with spring data .. Once this works am planning to add more complex things as can been seen in the methods idFilter() etc .

Comment: I am also unable to get a simple #{#variable} expression working.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing values of passed parameter objects by SpEL in general works like a charm and even your syntax seems correct.

Maybe compare it again with: [Spring Data JPA and SpEL](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions)

Are you really sure that the error message belongs to exactly your posted code? Did you adjust it later? I simplified it a little and this is a working test case example.

The Entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    public MyEntity(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

}
```

The Repository:

```
package com.example.repository;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.example.model.MyEntity;
import com.example.model.MyFilter;

public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.title = :#{#filter.title}")
    Page<MyEntity> list1(@Param("filter") MyFilter filter, Pageable pageable);

}
```

The "Filter":

```
package com.example.model;

public class MyFilter {

    private String title;

    public MyFilter(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

}
```

And the related Test:

```
package com.example.repository;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.model.MyEntity;
import com.example.model.MyFilter;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest
public class MyEntityRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

    @Test
    public void insertAndReceiveEntityBySpEL() {
        final String titleA = "A";
        final String titleB = "B";

        final MyEntity entityA = new MyEntity(titleA);
        final MyEntity entityB = new MyEntity(titleB);
        final MyEntity entityB2 = new MyEntity(titleB);

        myEntityRepository.save(entityA);
        myEntityRepository.save(entityB);
        myEntityRepository.save(entityB2);

        final MyFilter filterA = new MyFilter(titleA);
        final MyFilter filterB = new MyFilter(titleB);

        assertThat("Expected one hit for value A!", myEntityRepository.list1(filterA, new PageRequest(0, 5)).getContent().size(), is(1));
        assertThat("Expected two hits for value B!", myEntityRepository.list1(filterB, new PageRequest(0, 5)).getContent().size(), is(2));
    }

}
```

Maybe you can simplify also your code and find out what exactly is going wrong there. The SpEL expression should not be the real problem.

Some other things also can't be the cause of your error but nevertheless it seems strange:

- What are the methods `titleFilter()` and `idFilter()` for? Your are not using it here and it won't be used by the query.
- How do you set / adjust the value of the member `title` of your `MyFilter` object at runtime? Is it hardcoded only? And hence there is no getter, how should JPA access and use it for comparison?
- Why is your Repository extending `JpaSpecificationExecutor`?

The last thing is the most confusing. Is it possible that you want to work with [Specifications](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)? Then you need some `Predicate` checks to realize your "Filter".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I missed "addtional" # character inside the query curly braces, so in your case you would have:

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM eg.domain.MyEntity e     WHERE e.title = ?#{filter.title}"
```

but should have

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM eg.domain.MyEntity e     WHERE e.title = ?#{#filter.title}"
```

Notice: `?#{filter.title}` instead of `?#{#filter.title}"`

This does not match exactly the code you pasted, but might help others.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String title = "title title1";
```

title of filter is private and I could not see any getter for this property. May be this the problem.

Comment: Nopes .. I tired with the getter and no luck

Comment: Have you tried other alternatives like `?#{filter.title}`